# string escaping in json object

Tags: javascript, node.js, string, express

I have this object that I send in response as json.

```
{"__type":"http:\\/\\/example.com\\/contracts\\/documents\\/rendering\\/instructions\\/1\\/0"}
```

I want response to be:

```
{"__type":"http:\/\/example.com\/contracts\/documents\/rendering\/instructions\/1\/0"}
```

but I get this:

```
{"__type":"http:\\/\\/example.com\\/contracts\\/documents\\/rendering\\/instructions\\/1\\/0"}
```

How do I **escape string** correctly, so I can get response string with **only one backslash**?

Comment: Why do you escape the string to begin with? `"http://example.com/contracts/documents/rendering/instructions/1/0"` is valid JSON, so why escape the `/` before you actually need it to be escaped?

Comment: A [mcve] might make this easier to understand. It's really not clear what is an object or what is JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
let str='{"__type":"http:\\/\\/example.com\\/contracts\\/documents\\/rendering\\/instructions\\/1\\/0"}'
let result = str.replace(/\\/g,'\\');
```